# Error:Not able to enter values into terminal window in bluej

Tags: java, bluej

My code

```
import java.io.*;

class test
{
    void main()throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br= new 
        BufferedReader(new 
        InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter a string");
        String s=br.readLine();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

When I compile this code it is compiled without any errors but when I run the program the terminal window pops up and prints the first line but I'm not able to enter value for String s..I tried using Scanner class but even that doesn't work.

**Note:** I'm facing this problem from the time I installed Bluej 4.1.0 ... earlier I had 3.1.7 and everything was working fine.

Comment: change the sinature of main method :public static void main(String args[])throws IOException

Comment: I figured out the problem.. the terminal window of the new version works in a different way the text box for entering values is at the bottom